# Copy a column selected by input box to the next available column on an existing sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, inputbox

Very new to VBA and I have a workbook with both values and free text survey responses. I'm trying to cut the Free Response Text columns to their own sheet in my workbook. The columns this free text will be in may vary depending on the survey data entered, so I've used the input box to allow the user to select the correct column to be copied.

I understand how to paste that data into specific columns in the new sheet, but this code may be run several times if there are multiple free text columns.

How can I adjust my code to paste to the next available column of the designated sheet?  Giving the option to select multiple, non-consecutive columns at once would also work.

```
Sub CopyFreeText()
    
    Dim MySelection As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set MySelection = Application.InputBox("Select the column to move.", "Move Column", Type:=8)
    If MySelection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'user canceled
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    MySelection.EntireColumn.Cut (Sheets("Free Text Response").Range("A:A"))
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Received and answer elsewhere.

```
Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngB As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set rngA = Application.InputBox("Select the column to move.", "Move Column", Type:=8)
If rngA Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'user canceled
On Error GoTo 0

rngA.Copy
With Sheets("Free Text Response")
  
    Set rngB = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not rngB Is Nothing Then
        .Cells(1, rngB.Column + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Else
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If
End With
rngA.Clear
```

basically it works like this:
copy selection (the columns) > paste to target sheet > clear the initial selection

Edit: you need to select the whole column